# addEventListener does not work within a useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

The following is a component whose functionality, partly, is to change the window's title as the page is getting focused and blurred. It does not work.

```
const ATitleChangingComponent = () => {

    const focusFunction = (event: FocusEvent) => {
            document.title = "focused";
    };
    const blurFunction = (event: FocusEvent) => {
            document.title = "blurred";
    };


    useEffect(() => {
            window.addEventListener("focus", focusFunction);
            return window.removeEventListener("focus", focusFunction);
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
            window.addEventListener("blur", blurFunction);
            return window.removeEventListener("blur", blurFunction);
    }, []);

    return <p>some unimportant jsx</p>
};
```

However,

```
const focusFunction = (event: FocusEvent) => {
    document.title = "focused";
}; 
window.addEventListener("focus", focusFunction);
```

works just fine.

A side question: are `const focusFunction` and `const blurFunction` getting constructed within the function each render? I assume if so, they should be lifted out of the component to avoid unnecessary overhead?

Comment: `window.addEventListener("focus", focusFunction);
            return window.removeEventListener("focus", focusFunction);` <-- what is that? Why are you adding the event and removing it and returning what removeEventListener returns?

Comment: @epascarello Returning a function that will be used to clean up once the component dismounts. I should return `() => window.remove...`, however this change still did not make it work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Need to return a function, otherwise listener is removed immediately.

The function gets called when the component unmounts

```
useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("blur", blurFunction);
        return () => window.removeEventListener("blur", blurFunction);
}, []);
```

Comment: Just realized it. After the change it still does not work, however.

Comment: Not sure why...have done same thing with other listeners on window. A demo would help

Comment: Your change to the code in the question is enough. In the original code, somebody changed `window.addEvent...` to `document.addEvent...` and it was the second thing breaking it.

Comment: "The function gets called when the component unmounts" - why? Doesn't the return get executed each time useEffect is called, so I thought it would just execute the function upon return and remove the event listener..?

Comment: @bot19 In the code in the question `removeEventListener` gets called every time useEffect is called (the difference between returning `func` and `func()`), and that's what's wrong with that code. charlietfl's code corrected it - useEffect returns a function that gets called by React internals only on the last render.

Comment: @JohnSmith thanks for the reply, I wanted to know why if useEffect returns a function, it only gets called by react internals on the last render. Is that documentation somewhere? By last render do you mean on component unmount? Thanks

Comment: @bot19 Yes, it's a hook thing. It gets called on component unmount to let you do things like removing event listeners etc. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup